# Doctrine ODM embeded document parent reference

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, odm

I am working with an embbeded document currently, and I need to get the account information from the parent document to generate an URL. How can I access the parent document from a getter on the embedded document?

```
/** @Document */
class User
{
    // ...

    /** @EmbedOne(targetDocument="Image") */
    private $image;

    /** @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Account") */
    private $account;
    // ...
}

/** @EmbeddedDocument */
class Image
{
    private $url;

    public function getUrl(){
       // sudo code. How do I do this?
       return $this->getParent()->getAccount()->getDomain().$this->url;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid you can't
if its embedded  when you access Image you do it from User Document

```
$image = $user->getImage();
```

so you have also access to account like this

```
$account = $user->getAccount();
```

You should write a twig helper or a custom function to build your url from  User Document

I hope this help a little